# Setting in home ceiling speakers

Tags: home

Recently I bought a house with ceiling speakers set up in 6 rooms including the patio. The wires all end up close to the TV. So I thought of setting them all with the following requirements. Not sure if all of these are possible.

a) Connect all the speakers in all the rooms, with the ability to turn on/off any particular room at any time.

b) In the TV room, get a sound bar with a subwoofer and use the 2 ceiling speakers as rear

c) Ability to play from a different source of audio say, in the conservatory room while we watch football in the TV room.

I have no clue where to start.